# Which one is faster to execute?

Tags: c++, performance, qt

```
int value = 0;
foreach (QString string, stringlist)
  if(value < this->returnMaximum(Timer.value(string)->Ok->elapsed(),
                                 Timer.value(string)->Nok->elapsed(),
                                 Timer.value(string)->Err->elapsed()))
     value = this->returnMaximum(Timer.value(string)->Ok->elapsed(),
                                 Timer.value(string)->Nok->elapsed(),
                                 Timer.value(string)->Err->elapsed());
```

or

```
int value = 0;
foreach (QString string, stringlist)
{
  int max = this->returnMaximum(Timer.value(string)->Ok->elapsed(),
                                Timer.value(string)->Nok->elapsed(),
                                Timer.value(string)->Err->elapsed()));
  if(value < max)
     value = max;
}
```

and

```
inline int returnMaximum(int _a, int _b, int _c)
{
int max = _a;
(max < _b) && (max = _b);
(max < _c) && (max = _c);
return max;
}
```

Obviously in second one you reduce one function call, but I am wondering if one function call can cost me a lot, because frankly I like the first more.

Comment: Interesting way of naming variables in the second piece. Shouldn't `value` be called `max`, and `max` be called `value`?

Comment: Just remember: the more functions you call, the more likely your code would be slower.

Comment: There is one easy way to find out: Test both versions and compare performance. Your question greatly depends on `returnMaximum`. Apart from that I honestly like the second one *much* more. It is not redundant and clearly describes what it does. The first one, however keeps you comparing code for a few seconds.

Comment: The first one, definitely. You could do it even faster if you called `returnMaximum` again, just to be sure.

Comment: @jogojapan youre right, I just copied the first one and modified it...

Comment: The best thing you can do is omit the use of Qt's `foreach`, which makes a copy of the container it operates on.

Comment: Why `(max < _b) && (max = _b)` when you seem to know what an `if` statement is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compiler is naive, the first solution requires you to call about 7 other functions (which might call functions themselves). Apart from that, you have 6 other indirections in the function arguments. But it depends a lot on the functions, actually. The compiler may improve your situation a lot.

As for all is-this-faster-than-that issues, however, you should do measurements for your specific code. If you do not use this code snippet a lot, you do not need to optimize it a lot.

Apart from that, I would ask myself whether the first or second code snippet is more readable. I would go for the second solution in terms of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Second call is cheaper. In first sample you have one more function call + calculations in this function. So in this situation you are doing twice as work as needed.

Comment: I strongly disagree. How would you prove it?

Comment: 1. Make two examples and run benchmarks.
2. In small examples, where calculations in functions are just 1-2 lines, calling to function is around 20-40% of overall speed.
3. Usually in C you have max() function. In most cases if you rewrite this function to be inlined you will gain speed. So functions calls can't be avoided.
4. There are cases where compiler may optimized the two call to one single call, but you have to tried it. It is compiler based.

Comment: The question is tagged C++ and `std::max` is a template, so it's implicitly inline. 2) is just completely wrong without more information. With an at least decent compiler, the call will be inlined if possible, even across translation units. Even if it wasn't inlined, "overall speed" means the total speed, and you don't know how big the program is and how often the function is called. Also, 2 lines is relative - you can do a lot in 2 lines of code. As for 1) - until you make those benchmarks, it's a non-argument.

Comment: So first sample will be:
1. Same as first if you depend on compiler
2. Slower than second if compiler don't optimize it.
Can't understand why you should risk using first sample.

P.S. "Overall speed" means total function execution time. With 1-2 lines I meant something like max() function. Also I have made benchmarks with max() function and I'm sure in what I'm saying. Also making such a benchmark is about 10-15 lines of code. So it is easy to be checked by everyone in a minute.

Comment: I never said that. I'm just saying your statement is too powerful without any support. "Second call is cheaper." - no, it *might* be cheaper.

Comment: Actually I meant that second call will always be same or cheaper than first.

Answer (score 0):

If you raelly care, benchmark and see.

As a rule of thumb, if they don't end up the same after optimisation, you can expect that the second one will be the better performing.  This is especially likely if the `returnMaximum` function is not inlined, which can prevent the optimiser determining whether a second function call is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

the first one should be slightly faster. But the difference could be only on a very basic compiler. After Optimization Both might actually end up same in a modern day compiler. For accurate results try Bench marking.